# Evento blur sobre un div

Tags: javascript, div, blur

Estoy trabajando con un buscador a base javascript y similar al del navegador Firefox.

Cuando uso el evento `keyup` con la tecla Escape, sí se cierra correctamente el dialogo de resultados, pero no así con el evento `blur`.

Cuando selecciono con click el input con evento `keyup` y otra función con evento `focus`, se abre el dialogo de resultados. Al `dialogo` le agrego `focus()` para luego usar `blur()` pero, no me funciona de ninguna manera.

Lo mas cercano que logre es lo siguiente; pero esto no me funciona del todo ya que, al hacer click sobre el mismo `dialogo`, de igual forma se cierra. Por ejemplo, al hacer click en el `footer` del `dialogo`, se cierra.

```
function busquedaFuera() { // Cerrar centro de búsqueda

    dialogo.classList.remove("visible");
    yoBusqueda.classList.remove("activo");
    Input.blur();
    Input.value = "";
    info.innerText = `Escribe algo para buscar o elije una opción`;
    dialogo.blur();
};

yoBusqueda.addEventListener("blur", () => {

    // NO ME FUNCIONA EL BLUR SOBRE UN DIV CLASS
    if(dialogo) busquedaFuera();

}, true );
```

```js
const yoBusqueda = document.getElementById("yoBusqueda");
const Input = document.getElementById("yoBusqueda-input");
const dialogo = document.getElementById("yoBusqueda-dialogo");
const result = document.getElementById("resultados");

function resu(results) { // Abrir centro de búsqueda y resultados

    yoBusqueda.classList.add("activo");
    dialogo.classList.add("visible");
    dialogo.focus();
}

function busquedaFuera() { // Cerrar centro de búsqueda

    dialogo.classList.remove("visible");
    yoBusqueda.classList.remove("activo");
    Input.blur();
    Input.value = "";
    info.innerText = `Escribe algo para buscar o elije una opción`;
    dialogo.blur();
};

Input.addEventListener("focus", (e) => resu(e) );


yoBusqueda.addEventListener("blur", () => {

    // NO ME FUNCIONA EL BLUR SOBRE UN DIV CLASS
    if(dialogo) busquedaFuera();

}, true );

window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {

    // SI FUNCIONA
    if(e.key === "Escape" && dialogo.classList.contains("visible")) busquedaFuera();
});
```

```css
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 0;
    display: none;
} *::-webkit-scrollbar-button:increment, ::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    display: none;
} *::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: transparent;
} * {
    outline: 0;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    scrollbar-color: transparent transparent;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
} *, ::before, ::after {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

:root {
    --height50: 50px;
    --heightNav: 40px;
    --textoMini: .50rem;
    --textoPeque: .80em;
    --colorBlanco: rgb(255 255 255);
    --colorAzul: rgb(58 133 156);
    --colorGris: rgb(204 204 204);
    --colorIconos: rgb(255 228 196);
    --fondoNegro: rgb(0 0 0);
    --fondoPrimario: rgb(33 46 55);
    --fondoSecundario: rgb(43 48 59);
    --fondoSecundarioTransparente: rgba(43 48 59 / 0.5);
    --fondoNegroTransparente: rgba(0 0 0 / 0.5);
    --fondoBlancoTransparente: rgba(255 255 255 / 0.3);
    --fondoRojoTransparente: rgba(255 0 0 / 0.3);
    --bordeRadius-30rem: .30rem;
    --transicionNormal: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
} html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
} body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: normal;
    font-family: sans-serif
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: lightblue
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: .50rem;
    list-style: none
}

.m-r-5, .bi-r-5::before {margin-right: 5px}
.m-l-5, .bi-l-5::before {margin-left: 5px}

headland, .headland {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: var(--height50);
    padding: 0 1rem;
    background-color: var(--fondoNegroTransparente);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000
}

.yoBusqueda {
    display: block;
    width: 40vw;
    height: fit-content;
    min-height: var(--heightNav);
    max-height: 75vh;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 0;
    border-radius: var(--bordeRadius-30rem);
    background-color: var(--fondoNegroTransparente);
    transition: var(--transicionNormal)
} .yoBusqueda .yoBusqueda-btnMovil {
    display: none
} .yoBusqueda-dialogo {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    border-radius: var(--bordeRadius-30rem);
    background-color: var(--fondoNegroTransparente);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.3s
} .yoBusqueda-dialogo.visible {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    height: auto;
    background-color: var(--fondoSecundario)
}

.yoBusqueda-header {
    display: flex;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: var(--heightNav);
    padding: 0 .50rem;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: var(--bordeRadius-30rem);
    background-color: var(--fondoPrimario)
} .yoBusqueda:hover .yoBusqueda-header, .yoBusqueda.activo .yoBusqueda-header {
    border-color: bisque;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px bisque
} .yoBusqueda-header.alerta {
    border-color: red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px red
} .yoBusqueda-header .yoBusqueda-input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: inherit;
    color: var(--colorBlanco)
} .yoBusqueda-header .yoBusqueda-input:focus {
    border-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 .25rem transparent
} .yoBusqueda-header .yoBusqueda-btn {
    white-space: nowrap
}

.yoBusqueda-body {
    flex: 1 1 ;
    max-height: 70vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
} .yoBusqueda-body .detalles {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: calc(100% - 2rem);
    height: var(--heightNav);
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    cursor: default;
    color: var(--colorGris);
    font-size: var(--textoPeque);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(17 34 51)
} .yoBusqueda-body .preBusqueda {
    display: block;
    width: 100%
} .yoBusqueda-body .resultados, .yoBusqueda-body .preBusqueda.pre {
    display: none
} .yoBusqueda-body .resultados.visible {
    display: block
} .yoBusqueda-body .preBusqueda, .yoBusqueda-body .resultados {
    max-height: calc(100% - var(--heightNav) * 2);
    overflow-y: auto
} .yoBusqueda-body ul {
    padding: 0 .50rem;
    width: 100%
}

.yoBusqueda-body li, .yoBusqueda-body li a, .yoBusqueda-body .aGoogle {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px
} .yoBusqueda-body li {
    cursor: default
} .yoBusqueda-body li, .yoBusqueda-body .aGoogle {
    margin-bottom: 5px
} .yoBusqueda-body li:hover {
    background-color: var(--fondoBlancoTransparente)
} .yoBusqueda-body li a {
    padding: 0 .50rem
} .yoBusqueda-body .aGoogle li.disabled a {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.5
} .yoBusqueda-body .aGoogle li.disabled:hover {
    background-color: var(--fondoRojoTransparente)
} .yoBusqueda-body li a:hover {
    background-color: var(--fondoVerdeTransparente)
}

.yoBusqueda-footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: var(--heightNav);
    padding: 0 1rem;
    border-top: 1px solid var(--colorNegroTransparente);
    border-radius: 0 0 var(--bordeRadius-30rem) var(--bordeRadius-30rem);
    background-color: var(--fondoPrimario)
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<headland class="headland" id="headland">
        
        <div class="yoBusqueda" id="yoBusqueda">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary yoBusqueda-btnMovil bi-search" id="yoBusqueda-btnMovil"></button>
            <div class="yoBusqueda-header">
                <input type="text" class="btn btn-sm yoBusqueda-input" placeholder="Buscar algo" id="yoBusqueda-input">
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary yoBusqueda-btn">Botón</button>
            </div>
            <div class="yoBusqueda-dialogo" id="yoBusqueda-dialogo">
                <div class="yoBusqueda-body">
                    <div class="detalles">
                        <span id="infoResultado">Escribe algo para buscar o elije una opción</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="resultados" id="resultados"></div>
                    <div class="preBusqueda" id="preBusqueda">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#no">Enlace resultado</a> </li>
                            <li>No es enlace</li>
                            <li><a href="#no">Enlace resultado</a> </li>
                            <li>No es enlace</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="aGoogle">
                        <li class="disabled"><a href="#no" class="bi-google bi-r-5">Buscar <b class="esto m-l-5 m-r-5"></b> en Google</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="yoBusqueda-footer">
                    footer 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </headland>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que el evento `blur` funcione en un `div` debes agregar el atributo `tabindex` en el `div`

Revisar los siguientes ejemplos, debes hacer click intermitentemente en ambos cuadradados

**Ejemplo SIN tabindex (No se ejecutará)**

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".cuad").forEach(e=>e.addEventListener("blur",Blur));

function Blur(event){
  console.log(event.target.innerText);
}
```

```css
.cuad{
 width:100px;
 height:50px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cuad" > TEST1</div>
<div class="cuad"> TEST2</div>
```

*Ejemplo CON tabindex (Lo mismo con el anterior, solo que ahora se agrega el atributo)*

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".cuad").forEach(e=>e.addEventListener("blur",Blur));

function Blur(event){
  console.log(event.target.innerText);
}
```

```css
.cuad{
 width:100px;
 height:50px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cuad" tabindex="0"> TEST1</div>
<div class="cuad" tabindex="1"> TEST2</div>
```

Comment: Muy bien, cambie `yoBusqueda.addEventListener("blur", ` por este: `dialogo.addEventListener("blur", ` y me funciona muy bien

Comment: Claro, usando `tabindex`